# How to return node name from a QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

I've been working on a simple `QTreeView` of a local directory. The goal is allow the user to browse to his/her directory and select the correct `csv` file.

I've created a `QFileSystemModel` and displayed it with a `QTreeView`. I'm confused how to get the filename from the currently selected node.

I've read through the documentation and I've found the following signal/slot pairing:

`connect(tree, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(handleTreeWidgetEvent(QModelIndex)));`

But I'm not sure what to do with the `QModelIndex` once activated. I know you're supossed to index the `QTreeView` with this index, but I'm not sure how.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT:** Adding code so people can see what I'm doing.

```
QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel;                        
model->setRootPath("/");                      

tree = new QTreeView;
tree->setModel(model);

tree->setRootIndex(model->index("/home/Missions/"));
tree->setColumnWidth(0, 350);          
connect(tree, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(handleTreeWidgetEvent(QModelIndex)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WhatEverClassInheritingQObject::handleTreeWidgetEvent(const QModelIndex& index)
{
   const QString valuablePathAskedFor(fileSystemModel->fileName(index));
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve the path as a `QString` in your `setData` method [via `filePath()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemmodel.html#filePath) method based just on the `QModelIndex`, so it will be called each time user has checked (or unchecked) some directory or file in your model being displayed, and then you need to store all these paths in some conatainer and implement method to return this:

```
bool MyQFileSystemModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (index.column() != 0 || role != Qt::CheckStateRole)
        return QFileSystemModel::setData(index, value, role);

    int newCheckState = value.toInt();
    QString filePath = filePath(index);

    if (newCheckState == Qt::Checked || newCheckState == Qt::PartiallyChecked )
        checkedPaths.insert(filePath);
    else
        checkedPaths.remove(filePath);

    emit dataChanged(index, index.child(index.row(),0));

    return true;
}

class MyQFileSystemModel : public QFileSystemModel
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
//...
QSet<QString> getChecked() const { return checkedPaths; }

private:
QSet<QString> chackedPaths;
//...
};
```